# Run function on posts sequentially

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have the following (resource intensive) function that I am triggering on the `save_post` action. It works perfectly when I save OR edit a **single post**. The problem is that I need to use it when importing multiple posts at the same time. I believe it is running this function across ALL imported (saved) posts at the same time.

How can I use the `save_post` action BUT only have this function execute on each post sequentially?

```
function getYouTubeTags( $post_id ) {
    // Terminate if post has any tags
    if ( has_term('', 'post_tag') ) {
        return;
    }

    $out = null;
    $video_id = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'rfvi_video_id', true );
    $tag_url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" . $video_id;
    $sites_html = file_get_contents($tag_url, null, null, 700, 7000);
    $html = new DOMDocument();
    @$html->loadHTML($sites_html);
    $meta_og_tag = null;

    foreach( $html->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $meta ) {
        if( $meta->getAttribute('property')==='og:video:tag' ){
            $meta_og_tag = $meta->getAttribute('content');
            $out[] = $meta_og_tag;
        }
    }
    if ( !empty($out) ) {
        return implode(',', $out);
    } else {
        return;
    }

}

// Add YouTube tags to post
function rct_save_post_terms( $post_id ) {
    $terms = getYouTubeTags( $post_id );
    wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $terms, 'post_tag', true );
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'rct_save_post_terms', 110, 1 );
```

Comment: Don't use `file_get_contents` for HTTP requests. Ever.

Comment: @ZekeSonxx Can you explain why? Is there a more efficient way to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: What about `CURL` instead of `file_get_contents`?

Comment: I thought about using CURL but still wondering why I should use file_get_contents. It works perfectly (other than the issue in this post) so I just wanted to know why I should use `file_get_contents` ever...